# Herkunft "Holland in Not"

Tags: etymology, idiom

"Holland (sei) in Not" sagt man, wenn guter Rat teuer ist und ein Unglück geschehen. Zur Herkunft dieses Sprichwortes vermag ich aber nichts besseres zu finden als einige Webseiten ([hier](https://www.helpster.de/holland-in-not-die-redewendung_202187), [hier](https://www.antenneunna.de/artikel/woher-kommtholland-in-not-624895.html), ...). Diese führen es durchaus plausibel, aber ohne irgendwelche Quellenangabe darauf zurück, dass Holland an die Nordsee grenzt und damit der Unbill dieser bei Sturmflut ausgesetzt ist, wenn die Deiche versagen.

Wie lange gibt es diese Redensart schon und lässt sich eine solche Herleitung etwas fundierter belegen? Warum gerade Holland und nicht bspw. Friesland, Kedingen, Dithmarschen oder die Uthlande, alles Regionen, die dem deutschen Sprachraum näher sind, auch an die Nordsee grenzen und ebenso Sturmfluten zur genüge kennen? Oder gibt es gar einen ganz anderen Ursprung dieser Redensart?

Comment: @infinitezero Das Sprichwort gibt es tatsächlich auch auf niederländisch, dort heisst es *Bijt hem een vloo, soo is Holland in last* (Beißt ihn ein Floh, dann ist Holland [schon in] in Not) - Also nix mit Wasser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Sprichwort ist schon aus dem 16. Jahrhundert in Holland selbst [dokumentiert](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Da%2Bist%2BHolland%2Bin%2BNot&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou&sp1=rart_varianten_ou)

> Bijt hem een vloo, soo is Holland in last (Beißt ihn ein Floh, dann ist Holland [schon in] in Not)

als "Beißt ihn ein Floh, dann ist Holland in Not" - Als Ausdruck einer Überreaktion auf ein eigentlich lapidares Ereignis. Damit ist das Sprichwort ziemlich sicher aus dem Niederländischen übernommen. Man kann deswegen stark annehmen, dass "Holland in Not" in den Niederlanden schon zu dieser Zeit ein stehender Begriff war, der eine Katastrophensituation beschreibt.

Eigentlich ist die Herkunft Holländischer Sprichwörter hier off-topic, aber es ist einfach zu implizieren, dass in einem so flutgefährdeten (sei es durch Naturereignisse oder menschengemachte Fluten, wie z.B. als man durch die Öffnung der Deiche eine spanische und sehr viel später auch eine französische Invasion verhindern wollte) Land leicht von katastrophaler Not sprechen kann.